# How to add custom status to quick edit

Tags: publish, post-status, quick-edit, workflow

I have added some custom post status to WordPress, I can able display in New and Edit interfaces of POST. I would like to display those to quick edit too. Also I need to apply some condition to display custom status, I will explain with example.

Example : I have created status below
1)status-1
2)status-2

"status-1" appear in the drop-down box only if current post status is 'pending'.

"status-2" appear in the drop-down box only if current post status is 'status-1'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are no filters or actions for modifying the post status select in quick edit (`WP_Posts_List_Table::inline_edit()`) - you'd need to resort to JavaScript:

```
(function($){
    $( "select[name=_status]" ).each(
        function () {
            var value = $( this ).val();
            if ( value === "pending" )
                $( "option[value=pending]", this ).after( "<option value='status-1'>Status 1</option>" );
            else if ( value === "status-1" )
                $( "option[value=status-1]", this ).after( "<option value='status-2'>Status 2</option>" );

        }
    );
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thak you I will try this, I think I need to do some work on this code as this code need to call each time a user click on quick edit.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look below urls. It's a pretty detailed tutorial but can be quite involved, don't forget to check the comments area.

http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/expand-the-wordpress-quick-edit-menu
http://www.janes.co.za/add-to-custom-post-type-quick-edit-on-wordpress/

May this help you.